# Getting extras always null

Tags: android, android-activity, extras

Using a recycler view. On selecting an card I have put an intent on click of card in recyclerviews adapter which changes the activity by these lines of code

```
Intent i =new Intent (view.getContext(),ExpandedActivity.class);
            i.putExtra(passdate,members.getDate());
            view.getContext().startActivity(i);
```

members.getDate(); is having values as I can see by Toast

I want to pass a string to another activity but I am getting null in other activity. here is the code in another activity.

```
Bundle extras;
extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    date = extras.getString("passdate");
```

Making Toast of date shows null

Comment: members.getDate() is String Data?

Comment: Yeah it is an String data

Comment: Is passdate variable in putExtras = "passdate" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when we pass the data from onaActivity to AnotherActivity so Use **KEY** in **Double Quote**

```
     Intent i =new Intent (view.getContext(),ExpandedActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("passdate1",members.getDate1());
            i.putExtra("passdate2",members.getDate2());
            view.getContext().startActivity(i);


      String date1 = getIntent().getExtra().getString("passdate1");
      String date2 = getIntent().getExtra().getString("passdate2");
```

Comment: I have one more question how can I pass more than one values to the activity

Answer (score 2):

When putting values inside intent/bundle you have to provide a key under which you will store the value

**Setting the values**

```
Intent i = new Intent (view.getContext(), ExpandedActivity.class);
i.putExtra("KEY", members.getDate());
view.getContext().startActivity(i);
```

**Getting the values**

```
Bundle extras;
extras = getIntent().getExtras();
date = extras.getString("KEY");
```

Comment: I have one more question how can I pass more than one values to the activity

Comment: As you did with the first, just put multiple extras inside your intent. Again just call  `i.putExtra("ANOTHER_KEY", value);`

Answer (score 0):

You have to set KEY into double quote like below code:

```
Intent i =new Intent (view.getContext(),ExpandedActivity.class);
i.putExtra("passdate",members.getDate());
view.getContext().startActivity(i);
```

and for getting Intent data use below code:

```
String date = getIntent().getExtra().getString("passdate");
```